# How do I show that if $x''(t) + \lambda a(t) x = 0$ admits a non-zero solution satisfying $x(0) = 0$ and $x'(1) = 0$, then $\lambda > 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a: [0, 1] \rightarrow (0, + \infty)$ be a continuous function and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that if the differential equation $x''(t) + \lambda a(t) x = 0$ admits a non-zero solution satisfying $x(0) = 0$ and $x'(1) = 0$, then $\lambda > 0$.

What I have noticed so far:

If $x(t)$ is, as in the statement, not identically zero, then $x'(0) \neq 0$. Therefore the solution $x(t)$ crosses the x-axis at $t = 0$.

Further, $x''(0) = -\lambda a(0)x(0) = 0$ and since $a(t)$ is always positive, $x''(t)$ also crosses the x-axis at $t = 0$.

Therefore $x'(t)$ is not monotone.

When I draw some pictures and think about it, I can see that $x''(t)$ should be increasing (resp decreasing) when $x(t)$ is decreasing (resp increasing). And since $a(t)$ is always positive, and $x''(t) = - \lambda a(t) x(t)$, $\lambda$ has to be positive for this to happen.

Now, first of all, are my observations correct? Secondly, how would I go about proving this properly? I am struggling to put all of this together into a coherent argument.

Comment: If you're interested, an alternate approach involves multiplying through by x and integrating from 0 to 1, applying integration by parts to the first term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observations are correct, but I would try to argue locally on extremal points: Let $x \in C^2([0,1])$ be a non-trivial solution of this BVP. Since $-x$ solves the same BVP let $\max_{t \in [0,1]} x(t)> 0$, w.l.o.g., and let $t_0 \in (0,1]$ be such that $x(t_0)=\max_{t \in [0,1]} x(t)$.

Then $x'(t_0)=0$ (in case $t_0=1$ by the boundary condition), and by Taylor's Theorem
$$
x(t)=x(t_0)+x'(t_0)(t-t_0) + \frac{1}{2} x''(\xi(t))(t-t_0)^2 \quad (t \in [0,1] \setminus \{t_0\})
$$
with $\xi(t)$ between $t$ and $t_0$. Thus
$$
0 \ge x(t)-x(t_0)= \frac{1}{2} x''(\xi(t))(t-t_0)^2 \quad (t \in [0,1] \setminus \{t_0\})
$$
and $t \to t_0$ yields $x''(t_0) \le 0$.

Assume by contradiction that $\lambda  \le 0$. The case $\lambda =0$ can be trivially ruled out, so let $\lambda < 0$.

If $x''(t_0)=0$ we would get $x(t_0)=0$, hence $x=0$ (by unique solvability of IVPs). Thus $x''(t_0)< 0$. Hence
$$
0 > x''(t_0)= -\lambda a(t_0) x(t_0) > 0,
$$
a contradiction.